# All actions, responses, and votes tabs on my user profile are returning errors (usually)

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, 500-server-error

On my profile page, if I click on any of the last three tabs -- All actions, Responses, or Votes -- I get an error page.  All the other tabs work fine.  I think this is new within the last 12 hours or so.

I tested on several sites (Meta, Worldbuilding, Mi Yodeya, Community Building).  At first I thought the problem was that "private" tabs were broken (you can't see other people's responses or votes), but actions are public so it's not that.

Odd exception: on English Language & Usage, All actions results in an error but Responses and Votes work for me.  Other users (see comments) report different sites that do/don't work for them, so it's not a site-specific problem.  I can't identify anything that's different for me among the sites I tried.  (It's not moderator versus not; I'm not a moderator on Community Building or English.)

Comment: For me on SFF, All Actions work, Responses and Votes don't. On Meta, only Responses doesn't work. On Movies and Lit, everything works fine...

Comment: @Jenayah oh interesting, so it's not even per-site, if Meta works for you.  I just discovered the inverse of what you report on EL&U -- actions fail, responses and votes work.

Comment: It might even not be the sites (per se) at fault, apparently it works for someone else on SFF (see [Alex's reply in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50366174#50366174))

Comment: Everything works like a charm on mobile. FWIW, on computer I was on Windows 7, and one of the latest versions of Firefox (don't remember the number...).

Comment: I get 500 on Responses and Votes here, and [also on All actions on IPS Meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/server-error-when-attempting-to-access-all-actions-subtab-of-my-meta-profile).

Comment: I get [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP0Tm.jpg) on your profile and GP's on some sites,  OTOH other Sites such as SciFi and Quantum Computing work fine.

Comment: Error message for me when I switch to desktop on the votes page.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385255/all-activity-and-responses-show-oops-something-bad-happened

Comment: I dropped this in the dev chatroom for someone to hopefully take a look at.

Comment: Also reported on [Interpersonal Skills Meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3672/19693).

Comment: Similar problem for me on math.SE (all actions, Responses,Votes,...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on a certain timeline item type rendering a date block which had an errant translation in there. I've manually corrected the bad entry for now and we'll look at how to guard against it happening later - it *shouldn't* be allowed to happen but here we are so we'll look at improving that.

For the curious, it was ultimately calling `.Day` instead of `.Days` on a `TimeSpan` element in .NET with our generated code...and TimeSpan doesn't have a `.Day` so...kaboom. We'll think on how to validate this case that got through.

A fix is being deployed now, it should be out to all servers in about a minute.

Comment: Mind answering the [IPS Meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/server-error-when-attempting-to-access-all-actions-subtab-of-my-meta-profile) and [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385255/all-activity-and-responses-show-oops-something-bad-happened) cross-site dupes?

Comment: Yeah sure, done!

Comment: There's also a dupe on [TWP](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6158).