# Unable to access the default profile tab for users?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

If I try to access a user's profile (Examples: [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio), [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/users/7653/brock-adams), [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/14213/uhoh), etc.), it eventually times out and throws me to the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page ([Example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/14213/uhoh)).

This has been going on for a few minutes; anyone else seeing it?

Oddly enough, *directly* going to a different profile page sub-tab still works fine. ([Example, going straight to Activity tab](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/14213/uhoh?tab=topactivity))

Happens on multiple browsers.

Comment: [This same error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328451/323179) was just introduced and fixed yesterday, and now it's back.

Comment: Bluefeet sez: SQLServer is unhappy. We will make the necessary sacrifices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We send some read-only traffic to one of our secondary SQL Servers. It got a bit unhappy with lots of queries trying to hit it and we ended up with some blocking on the server.

I killed a bunch of sessions that were being blocked and things have settled back down. The pages should load again now that SQL is no longer angry.

Comment: Thanks, but that sounds like the bites have been stitched up, and the shark is still out there.  That is: will sessions become blocked again at some point?

Comment: @AwesomePoodles It's possible that it would happen again, but it's rare when it does.