# Stack Overflow loads extremely slow and sporadically appears as offline*

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

Everything loads *extremely* slow. No matter what I click. Sometimes the site appears offline. But when I check its status with [Down For Everyone Or Just Me](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/), it appears online.

I am getting random error messages like:

> An error has occurred - please retry your request.
>
> [image: An error has occurred - please retry your request]

or

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> [image: Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

or

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> [image: We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.]

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help redirects to [Oops! Something Bad Happened!](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/help)

Related to [Unable to access the default profile tab for users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328483/unable-to-access-the-default-profile-tab-for-users)

---

<sub>* EDIT – it would be awesome to know what caused all these issues.</sub>

Comment: Not just you. I got an "Under Maintenance" page at one point (but mostly just errors), so someone might just be fixing something.

Comment: It should be working now... mine is doing good

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: Being slow might mean their server side cache (Redis?) is busted... just a guess though.

Comment: Seems to be ok now; haven't noticed any issues since my original comment. By the way, it wasn't limited to Stack Overflow, I had the same errors on other sites as well (definitely on Super User and Ask Ubuntu, plus someone also mentioned math.se in chat).

Answer (score 12):

We had a couple of web servers that went off the rails. They ran out of threads and resulted in exceptions.

We have pulled both servers out of rotation and the exceptions settled down. We're still investigating the root cause of the issue.

Comment: You should feed those servers better. ;)

Comment: Off the Rails?  I thought this place was a Microsoft shop.

Comment: Could you share the results of the investigation?